js rendering problem in typo3 for <f.be.pageRenderer>
<f:be.pageRenderer pageTitle="{f:translate(key: 'pagetitle')}"
    includeRequireJsModules="{
        0:'TYPO3/CMS/NsExtCompatibility/Main'
    }"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{f:uri.resource(path:'Css/main.css', extensionName: 'ns_ext_compatibility')}" media="all" />
<f:flashMessages />
<f:render section="Content" />

I have added js like this, but it is not rendered in typo3.

The f:be.pageRenderer is used in backend only.
Assuming you try to add JS in a frontend plugin. You could use the f:asset.script viewHelper:
<f:asset.script identifier="identifier123" src="EXT:my_ext/Resources/Public/JavaScript/foo.js" />

https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/Global/Asset/Script.html
